# Walkhub - Missing "User_account_menu" Module in Drupal

Tags: github, drupal, module, installation

I am Trying to install Walkhub on my private server downloaded from Git https://github.com/Pronovix/WalkHub.

[image]

The installation was missing 3 modules and I have found 2 of them.

Now I am still missing the **User_account_menu** module and can`t find it anywhere.

[image]

Does someone know the location of the walkhub module or how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old version of WalkHub, that is unsupported. We did a switch from Drupal to a Go + React platform about a year ago. You can find the latest platform at: https://github.com/Pronovix/walkhub-service

Setting this up is a bit different than Drupal. If you just want to try it out, I recommend using the hosted version at https://walkhub.net.